# How do I obtain the second highest value in a row?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to obtain the second highest value of a certain section for each row from a dataframe. How do I do this?

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
df.iloc[:, 5:-3].nlargest(2)(axis=1, level=2)
```

Is there any other way to obtain this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using apply with axis=1 you can find the second largest value for each row. by finding the first 2 largest and then getting the last of them

```
df.iloc[:, 5:-3].apply(lambda row: row.nlargest(2).values[-1],axis=1)
```

Example

The code below find the second largest value in each row of df.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Col{}'.format(i):np.random.randint(0,100,5) for i in range(5)})

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0    82    32    14    62    90
1    62    32    74    62    72
2    31    79    22    17     3
3    42    54    66    93    50
4    13    88     6    46    69

In [5]: df.apply(lambda row: row.nlargest(2).values[-1],axis=1)
Out[5]: 
0    82
1    72
2    31
3    66
4    69
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you need sorting per rows and then select:

```
a = np.sort(df.iloc[:, 5:-3], axis=1)[:, -2]
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,10)))
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  8  8  3  7  7  0  4  2  5  2
1  2  2  1  0  8  4  0  9  6  2
2  4  1  5  3  4  4  3  7  1  1
3  7  7  0  2  9  9  3  2  5  8
4  1  0  7  6  2  0  8  2  5  1
5  8  1  5  4  2  8  3  5  0  9
6  3  6  3  4  7  6  3  9  0  4
7  4  5  7  6  6  2  4  2  7  1
8  6  6  0  7  2  3  5  4  2  4
9  3  7  9  0  0  5  9  6  6  5

print (df.iloc[:, 5:-3])
   5  6
0  0  4
1  4  0
2  4  3
3  9  3
4  0  8
5  8  3
6  6  3
7  2  4
8  3  5
9  5  9

a = np.sort(df.iloc[:, 5:-3], axis=1)[:, -2]
print (a)
[0 0 3 3 0 3 3 2 3 5]
```

If need both values:

```
a = df.iloc[:, 5:-3].values
b = pd.DataFrame(a[np.arange(len(a))[:, None], np.argsort(a, axis=1)])
print (b)
   0  1
0  0  4
1  0  4
2  3  4
3  3  9
4  0  8
5  3  8
6  3  6
7  2  4
8  3  5
9  5  9
```

Comment: Hey! This is a very good solution. This is not outputting the second highest value. There are few empty values in my rows and this outputs empty values.

Comment: Can you add data sample and expected output with empty values?

Comment: `a = np.sort(df.iloc[:, 5:-3], axis=1)[:, -2]` is the correct answer. Indexing with `[:, 0]` only works by accident because you are using a 10x2 slice. If you create a larger dataset (say 16x16), it will become obvious.

Answer (score 0):

One fun option is a creative of the pandas 'replace' functionality.

First, get the maximum values for each row:

```
max_values = values.max()
```

Then subtract these maximum values from your overall data frame -- then, the positions that had that maximum value will then be zeroed out.

```
values_with_max_pos_zeroed_out = values_for_cycle - max_values_for_cycle
```

Then, when you replace the zeros with nan, the max function ignores nans such that you can take that difference from the original max values, and add it back to the max values to get what the second highest values are for each row:

```
max_values+(values_with_max_pos_zeroed_out ).replace(0, np.nan).max()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to sort your dataframe with `numpy.sort()` and then get the second value.

```
import numpy as np
second = np.sort(df.iloc[:, 5:-3], axis=1)[:, 1]
```

Comment: Do you test it?

Comment: Yes, I did. This outputs the second lowest value in the row.

Comment: Because if use `[:, 1]` it return for me first max value.

Comment: `[:, 1]` returns the second lowest value.